# iOS Swift4 how to protect computed property defined in interface from assignment?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, mocking, computed-properties

I'm debugging some poorly written unit tests for a class from a legacy code base I inherited. I see that the developer is not testing the computed property correctly. I want to understand how to enforce my `userEnabledFeature` to be read only in the Fake class.

**Why class implementing protocol with computed property can overwrite the computed property and make it writable?**

```
public protocol FeatureManager {
    var userEnabledFeature : Bool { get }
}

public class FakeFeatureManagerForTesting: FeatureManager {
    public var userEnabledFeature = false //is this legal? Why is compiler not complaining?

    public func updateUserEnabledFeature(enabled: Bool){
        //this should not be possible - how do I prevent overwriting computed property?
        userEnabledFeature = enabled
    }
}

ActualFeatureManagerClass {
    public var userEnabledFeature: Bool {
        if featureManager.cachedFeatures.filter { $0.enabled == true}
        {
            //do more checks, return true or false
        }
        return false //default
    }
}
```

Comment: Change the property in `FakeFeatureManagerForTesting` to: `public var userEnabledFeature: Bool { return false }`

Answer (score 1):

```
public class FakeFeatureManagerForTesting: FeatureManager {
  public var userEnabledFeature = false //is this legal? Why is compiler not complaining?
}
```

The protocol is saying that members that conform to it must have a `Bool` property `userEnabledFeature` that can be read, not that it is read-only property. However, if you have a variable which has the protocol as type, it will not allow you to assign the property even if the value of the variable is implementation has it writable too.

Protocol is not defining how is it implemented (if its computed property, stored property etc), but what is its signature and if it **should** be read only or **must have** write-access too. If you mark it as read-only, the implementation can still make write writable as the protocol does not really care about write-access in that case.

You can achieve computed property like this:

```
public class FakeFeatureManagerForTesting: FeatureManager {
  public var userEnabledFeature: Bool { 
    // do some work here and return value or fallback to false
    return false
  }
}
```

On the other hand, you can also have only private settable property, that can be changed from file or class/struct only:

```
public class FakeFeatureManagerForTesting: FeatureManager {
  public private(set) var userEnabledFeature = false

  public func updateUserEnabledFeature(enabled: Bool) {
    userEnabledFeature = enabled // will work just fine
  }
}

let manager = FakeFeatureManagerForTesting()
manager.updateUserEnabledFeature(enabled: true) // will work
manager.userEnabledFeature = true // won't compile, because modifying is allowed privately only
```